# How to click on the center of the button using selenium java? Which position of the button is actually getting clicked when button is identified?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I have button in our website, and border areas of the button is not clickable. So, i need to make sure the button is getting clicked at the center. Is it possible via selenium?

I tried using coorinates, but it is not recommended for our scenario.

xpath used : `//div/button[@id='clickme']`

```
<div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-12 p-0 pt-4">
    <button class="click mb-3 " tabindex="0" id="clickme">+&nbsp;Click Here</button>
</div>
```

Java code used to click

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.id("clickme"));
button.click();
```

I guess the click is happening sometimes[2 out of 10 times] on the border where it is not clickable(hand symbol not shown) .  As a result report says the click action happened, but there is no event fired on the website.

Comment: It's great that you provided the HTML code, but please also specify which language you're using and show the code you are using to perform the click.  Add these things to your original post.  The more information you provide, the likelier it is you'll get help.

Comment: try with javascript executor click.

Comment: I believe Selenium's click action always clicks the center.  (moves to center first...)

Comment: @BillHileman   I have updated the question with your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

To identify the element with text as **Click Here** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  "button.click#clickme"
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  "//button[contains(@class, 'click') and @id='clickme'][contains(., 'Click Here')]"
  ```